# Discordjs dm certain user

Tags: discord.js

I've currently tried to dm a certain user with a id of, e.g., `693301017365839952`.

My code so far is

```
if (message.content === '.dm') {
    const user = client.cache.get('693301017365839952');
    user.send("This is a test");
    
  }
```

What I get back is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`...

Anyone have a solution to this? (Any help is appreciated.)

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as `client.cache`. What you're looking for is [`client.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users)[`.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=cache)[`.get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get).

---

```js
const user = client.users.cache.get("693301017365839952");
user.send("This is a test").catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote I accidentally missclicked. Will be fixed when possible